# Как получить стиль родительского элемента через дочерний?

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, html, css

Есть такая функция

```
function mDown(e){
        e.target.style.position = 'absolute';
            e.target.style.width = /*ширина родителя*/;
        return false;
    }
```

Как через event.target обратиться к style родителя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

стряпал для примера

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
    <div id="children"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getParentCss(e)
{
    alert(e.parentNode.getAttribute('style'));
}

function setParentCss(e, newCss)
{
    e.parentNode.setAttribute('style', newCss);
}

getParentCss(document.getElementById('children'));

setParentCss(document.getElementById('children'), 'border: 1px solid #000; width: 200px; height: 200px;');
</script>
```